# MySQL listing categories with links

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I speak a little English. It's ok:

```
SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `state` = TRUE ORDER BY `title` ASC
```

I would like:

```
SELECT *, cnt FROM `category` WHERE `state` = TRUE ORDER BY `title` ASC
```

The cnt is count link(category-id)/category(id).

```
CREATE TABLE category ( id );
CREATE TABLE link ( id, category-id ); -- link(category-id)=category(id)
```

How many links per categories?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Join the `link`table and group by all columns you want to select from the `category` table

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, count(l.id) as cnt 
FROM `category` c
left join link l on l.category_id = c.id
WHERE c.`state` = 1
GROUP BY c.id, c.title
ORDER BY c.`title` ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think it is wrong. It is not work for me.